# Spring custom validator not being called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, customvalidator

I am creating a custom validator with Spring and Java 17.0.8 to validate names in a `Person` class. However, it is not being called.

Annotation:

```
package com.example.demo.validation;

import jakarta.validation.Constraint;
import jakarta.validation.Payload;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;

@Target( { FIELD, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = NameValidator.class)
public @interface NameValidation {
public String message() default "Invalid Name";
public Class\<?\>\[\] groups() default {};
public Class\<? extends Payload\>\[\] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator class:

```
package com.example.demo.validation;

import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class NameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NameValidation, String> {
    public boolean isValid(String name, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        // For simplicity of this example, we only check whether the value is null
        return name != null;
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
package com.example.demo.api;

import com.example.demo.model.Person;
import com.example.demo.service.PersonService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.\*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@Validated
@RequestMapping("api/v1/person")
@RestController
public class PersonController {
private final PersonService service;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping
    public void addPerson( @Valid @RequestBody Person person) {
        service.insertPerson(person);
    }

}
```

Service class:

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.dao.PersonDAO;
import com.example.demo.model.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
public class PersonService {

    public int insertPerson(Person person) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Person class:

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import com.example.demo.validation.NameValidation;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.UUID;

public class Person {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
    
    private final UUID id;
    
    @NameValidation
    private final String name;
    
    
    public Person(@JsonProperty("id") UUID id, @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Remove `jakarta.validation-api` dependency and fix your `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency. Your current `pom.xml` (at least what you added here) isn't even a valid one. Finally remove `@Validated` from the controller that is not needed (and was probably added in an attempt to fix it).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your response. If I remove `jakarta.validation-api` how do I import annotations such as `@valid` and `@Constraint` ?

Comment: You seem to be doing the right thing code like. Just replace `jakarta.validation-api` with `org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.010.Final` and I think it should work. This is what we use anyway and it does.

Comment: You should have a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-validator`, which is what I also explained you need to fix.

Comment: Adding the dependency `spring-boot-starter-validator` resolved the problem. Thank you.